# How to construct many-to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

I'm my project I have two tables, Jobs and Counties.  Each job record can be associated with many counties.  So first, this is a many to many relationship correct?

I'd like to have a fieldset of checkboxes in my jobs form that if a checkbox is checked a relationship between the job_id and the checked county_id is made.

So I'm thinking I need a join table with only job_id and county_id, correct?

Here's what I have so far.  So far it'll save a job record, but not the job/county associations.

"counties_jobs_join" migration

```
class CreateCountiesJobsJoin < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :counties_jobs, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :county_id
      t.integer :job_id
    end
  end
end
```

"counties" model

```
class County < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :jobs
end
```

"jobs" model

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :counties
end
```

As for my form, I'm using simple_form, so here's what I have for the checkboxes.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@job) do |f| %>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Counties</legend>
    <%= f.association :counties, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => County.all.sort, :selected => @job.counties, :label => false %>
  </fieldset>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

I've checked in the database, but it's not creating any records in counties_jobs.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: need params from log that submitted to create action

Comment: if you ask any question than please provide any detail asked so it will be easier to provide solutions. keep responsive towards your question :)

Comment: accepts_nested_attributes_for :counties put this in model Job

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say what is going wrong with you creation but I think it is not a problem of your habtm relationship. In fact, if you can see the counties checkboxes, I can assure you your relationship is working.

Probably what it is not happening is that either you are not allowing :accept_nested_attributes or not doing it manually in your create controller.